# Running SBT (Scala) on several (cluster) machines at the same time

Tags: scala, sbt, actor, akka

So I've been playing with Akka Actors for a while now, and have written some code that can distribute computation across several machines in a cluster. Before I run the "main" code, I need to have an `ActorSystem` waiting on each machine I will be deploying over, and I usually do this via a Python script that SSH's into all the machines and starts the process by doing something like `cd /into/the/proper/folder/` and then `sbt 'run-main ActorSystemCode'`.

I run this Python script on one of the machines (call it "Machine X"), so I will see the output of SSH'ing into all the other machines in my Machine X SSH session. Whenever I do run the script, it seems all the machines are re-compiling the entire code before actually running it, making me sit there for a few minutes before anything useful is done.

My question is this:

1. Why do they need to re-compile at all? The same JVM is available on all machines, so shouldn't it just run immediately?
2. How do I get around this problem of making each machine compile "it's own copy"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sbt is a build tool and not an application runner. Use sbt-assembly to build an all in one jar and put the jar on each machine and run it with `scala` or `java` command.

Comment: Well it's a cluster so they all share the same partition (NFS).. can a single jar be run on multiple machines?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work. Try it and if it does not work you can still create multiple copies of the jar.

Answer (score 4):

It's usual for cluster to have a single partition mounted on every node (via NFS or samba). You just need to copy the artifact on that partition and they will be directly accessible in each node. If it's not the case, you should ask your sysadmin to install it.

Then you will need to launch the application. Again, most clusters come 
with MPI. The tools `mpirun` (or `mpiexec`) are not restricted to real MPI applications and will launch any script you want on several nodes.

Comment: I THINK the cluster does have a single partition on each node using NFS. If this is the case (sorry, I'm not too familiar with the lingo), what is this "artifact" that I need to copy?

Comment: Mainly the jar files. (and any ressources you may need such as config files, input files, etc.)